# Does handler belong to thread in which it was created?

Tags: android, android-handler, looper, android-looper, android-thread

I'm relatively new to the "Looper-Handler" term. I'm pretty clear with the way they work but still confused with their architecture.
I've also gone through couple of SO questions, but still I have some questions regarding them.

To get them clear and to summarize, can anyone answer for the below questions?

1. Is it true that the `Handler` belong to the thread in which it was created ?
2. I'm aware that there can be multiple instances of handler per `Looper/MeesageQueue` pair. Is it possible create a `handler` for a thread from some other Thread?
3. Suppose, in the main thread we write `Handler handler = new Handler (x.getLooper())` where x is the `handler` of another thread X, then to which MessageQueue `handler` will actually post?

If I'm getting wrong anywhere, please make me correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right, if you use default constructor `val h = Handler()`. Default constructor associates this handler with the [`Looper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/Looper) for the current thread. If this thread does not have a looper, this handler won't be able to receive messages so an exception is thrown.
2. Yes. If you use constructor, which accepts [`Looper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/Looper) `val h = Handler(looper)`, where `looper` associated with another `Thread`.
3. `handler` will be associated with `Thread` X, because looper of that thread is used to created the `handler`.

The 3rd question is similar to the 2nd one.

Comment: Thanks. You've talked about the constructor in 1st pt. In one of the similar question, someone was arguing over the version of SKD used. To does it matter really here? I mean would change in SDK version change any of the above answer?

Comment: I think it shouldn't depend on the version of SDK.